# explicitly behave as an interface

Tags: java

can we  make any class to behave as interface and so that we can write "implements" in place of "extends" while creating any child class of that class .what is the actual difference between "implements" and "extends" internally .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `interface` is like a blueprint. It doesn't define any behavior. Hence when you say *extends* in the context of an interface it means you are extending the blueprint but not adding behavior. Conversely, when you say *extends* in the context of a class it means you are adding/modifying the behavior. When you say *implements* it means you are going to provide something that has behavior i.e. a `class`

Comment: "It doesn't define any behavior". Well, that is not true. Most interfaces define in detail how they want to be implemented (in JavaDoc, not in code). See for example the hashCode() definitions for Set or List.

Comment: @Thilo: The usage of define here is just to distinguish from the actual behavior that functions in a class possess - in terms of code. You are right that we do use JavaDocs to provide expected behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand the question.

The Java language specification makes it clear that you can only extend classes and implement interfaces.

You could argue that you may want to use just the method headers of a class as an interface and implement that part (without inheriting the implementations), but you cannot do that with Java.

> what is the actual difference between "implements" and "extends" internally .

Implements registers an interface, extends registers a parent class.